# Can Sour/Acidic Food reduce libido in men?

Tags: sexual-arousal

I live in Asia which means I am surrounded by a lot of myths and superstitions. I have heard in here that if a man eats food that women eat while they have cravings during pregnancy (Sour/Acidic Food), the man can get himself something that is called ED or Erectile Dysfunction. Is it true by any means? is it even near to the truth? I like to eat sour food such as Tamarind, Pani Puri etc, so it would be very helpful for a person like me to get the answer to this questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erectile dysfunction (ED) can be caused by a wide variety of things [covered in this answer](https://health.stackexchange.com/a/7503), but it cannot be caused by eating the kind of foods you are talking about.